# Javascript Loop : cannot make my array

Tags: javascript

I try to make a loop to inject data into a array that look like this :

```
$scope.allImages = [{'src':json.pools[i].picture, 'width':'100'}];
```

I make a loop to 'inject' new pictures into the array but it doesn't work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.pools.length; i++) {

    $scope.allImages = [{'src':json.pools[i].picture, 'width':'100'}];

}
```

The actual result give me always the last record but it must be like this :

```
$scope.allImages = [
  {'src':'/picture/1.jpg', 'width':'100'},
  {'src':'/picture/2.jpg', 'width':'100'},
  {'src':'/picture/3.jpg', 'width':'100'} ...
];
```

How i can do this in the loop ?

Thank you

Comment: user .push to add element ton an array

Comment: Use `.map()` instead. `var $scope.allImages = json.pools.map(function(p) { return {src:p.picture, width:'100'} });`

Comment: Because you are initialising the array inside the loop so every iteration reassigns the loop and and the neweast value to it. If you initialize the array outside and then add values inside the loop using push it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.allImages = [];

for (var i = 0; i < json.pools.length; i++) {

    $scope.allImages.push({'src':json.pools[i].picture, 'width':'100'});

}
```